# GAE/J: Some objects not being persisted in the session despite being serializable

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf-2

I have a very strange issue in GAE/J. Things work in the local environment, but not on the GAE servers.

Environment: GAE/J 1.8.2 + JSF 2.2.1 + JPA

I have an object managed by JPA - let us call this X (implements Serializable)
I have a bean that is scoped to session map - let us call this Y (implements Serializable)

My class Y looks like the following.

```
@SessionScoped
class Y implements Serializable
{
  private X selectedObject;

  // Getter & setter for X
}
```

As part of an operation, I set the value of X and then redirect the user to a different page. When I access the bean in the second page, it tells me that no value has been set for X.

Now, my guess is that for some reason, GAE is not storing this reference to X in the datastore backed session. I have tried a variety of logging, and yet I am unable to figure out why is only X (a JPA entity) not being persisted along with the rest of the object to the session scope.

Any ideas of what might be going wrong here?

Thanks,
Harsha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. So I knew that in order to avoid the ViewExpiredException, one of the ways is to setup a phase listener which updates a random attribute into the session map, thereby forcing the serialization of the map to the data store. One mistake that I did was to have this phase listener doing this job in the afterPhase() of the RENDER_RESPONSE phase.

What I forgot taking in to account was the fact that a faces-redirect occurs in the INVOKE_APPLICATION phase ... meaning, my listener was never being invoked in the redirect case.

After changing the listener to ANY_PHASE and explicitly updating the session map for either the INVOKE_APPLICATION or RENDER_RESPONSE, I am now seeing the expected results.

The sample code for your reference.

```
public class SessionSerializationListener implements PhaseListener
{
    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event)
    {
        // Set an attribute on to the session just so that we can force the session to get serialized
        // We target the invoke application phase as well since the redirects get issued in that phase
        if (event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION || event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE)
        {
            // get hold of the session map
            sessionMap.put("__timestamp__", System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event)
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId()
    {
        return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
    }
}
```